# Is there a closed form for $ \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{x + i}\right)^{i y} $?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, exponential-sum

I would like to find a closed formula for this equation:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{x + i}\right)^{i y}
$$

Both the denominator and also the exponent is changing in each step. How is it possible to simplify it?

---

If the closed form does not exist for some reason, then I would like to find an approximation.

I have some experience with the sum of arithmetic and geometric progression, but this is something different, and I don't know, how to apply my previous knowledge here.

---

In my application the value of $n$ is usually between 50 and 1000, therefore $lim_{n \to \infty}$ may give a wrong result. $x$ is in the range $(-10, 10)$ where $x \neq 0$ and $y$ is in the range $(0, \frac{1}{10})$ where $y>0$

Comment: Is there a reason to think you can simplify it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just hope that I can, because that would speed up my program a lot

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I understand if it is not possible. But in that case, I would like to prove it.

Comment: I doubt its possible. What you can do instead is to approximate the summand for large $i$ which might help to sum it quicker. For example for $i \gg x$ you can show that the summand is $\simeq e^{-xy}(1 + x^2y/i)$.

Comment: The value of $n$ is usually between 50 and 1000

Comment: And what is the $x,y$ range you are interested in?

Comment: $x$ is usually in the range $(-10, 10)$ and $x \neq 0$. $y$ is usually in the range $(0, \frac{1}{10})$ and $y>0$

Comment: I would probably use $\left( \frac{i}{i+x} \right)^{iy} = e^{iy \log \left(1 - \frac{x}{i+x} \right)}$ if you're trying to speed up code? The log term also has a nice convergent power series but not sure you'd get enough cancellation to make it useful.

Comment: Perhaps it would motivate participants if you disclose some more details about the context of your question.
And why is speedup of your program so desperately needed?

Answer (score 2):

One thing is for sure: the terms in the sum converge to a constant, namely
$$
\lim_{i\to\infty} \left(\frac{i}{x + i}\right)^{i y} =
\frac{1}{\lim_{i\to\infty} \left[\left(1+\frac{x}{i}\right)^i\right]^y} = \frac{1}{[e^x]^y} = e^{-xy}
$$
Convergence of the terms may be very slow, depending on $x$.
Anyway, it means that the sum itself does not converge to anything: it is continuously increasing.